# Comparing Integer objects vs int

Tags: java

I fixed an endless loop by changing Integer to int in the following:

```
public class IntTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer x=-1;
        Integer total=1000;

        while(x != total){
            System.out.println("x =" + x + "total ="+ total);
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the proper reason for this?  I figured Integer would compare no problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You could also have changed "x != total" to "total != x".

Comment: Checkout http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=197

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because when you make != comparing on the object it compares the references. And the references between two objects in general case are different.

When you compare ints it always compares primitives, lets say not references( there are no objects ), but the values.

So, if you want to work with Integer you must use equals() on them.

Additionally, if your values are between 0 and 255 the comparison between Integer works fine, because of caching.

You can read here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html

Comment: On the other hand, if you used != between an Integer and an int, auto-unboxing would give you the result you expect.

Comment: How about comparing a primitive and an Object, like int and Integer ? Is that possible in java

Answer (score 6):

`Integer` is an `Object`, and objects are compared with `.equals(..)`

Only primitives are compared with `==`

That's the rule, apart from some exceptional cases, where `==` *can* be used for comparing objects. But even then it is not advisable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Integer is a class and therefore even comparison is done like for any other class - using the .equals() method. If you compare it using ==, you compare the references which are always different for two distinct instances.
The primitive type `int` is not a class but a Java built-in type and the comparison is thus handled specially by the compiler and works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Integer.intValue() to get the int value for comparison, if you truly need to use Integer at all.

Answer (score 1):

Integer is a class wrapper around the Java primitive type int. They are not the same thing. you should be using int instead of Integer unless you have a valid reason (such as `ArrayList<Integer> list`;