# Two integer value equal in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, integer, equals, record

In my below code i check the two `infocode` if it exist show `msg` `MSG_SAME_INFO_ALREADY_EXISTS` but the issue is that when i compare two `infocode` the infocode value is same but it cannot enter the loop .

What i am wrong in below code ?

```
if (folderInfoData.getFolderInforecord().getInfoCode() == map.get("infoCode")) {
    showError(pageResourceBundle.getText("MSG_SAME_INFO_ALREADY_EXISTS"));
    return;
    }
```

Both Debug value given below :

the both `folderInfoData.getFolderInforecord().getInfoCode()` and  `map.get("infoCode")` infocode return integer given below.

[image]
[image]

Can anyone tell me how can resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing Integer objects vs int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036167/comparing-integer-objects-vs-int)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing objects - [`Integer`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), the `==` operator might work only for numbers between [-128,127]. Look at the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the
>   range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127
>   (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing
>   conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.

Since that values you're comparing are not in the mentioned range, the result will be evaluated to `false`. You should use [`Integer#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead.

Comment: It doesn't even work reliably in that area, if one of the `Integer` values is not produced by autoboxing: `Integer i1 = 100; Integer i2 = new Integer(100); System.out.println(i1 == i2);`. This will print `false`. You should **always** use `equals` to compare `Integer`, no matter which range they are in.

Comment: @JoachimSauer That's how downvotes should be clarified :) Comments like that are extremely helpful for me and for OP.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing Object with `==` that is the issue. use `equals()` instead of `==`

Why should we use [equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772763/why-equals-method-when-we-have-operator)?

Read [this](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html) link for more info. and ᴍaroun ᴍaroun answer describe more.