# Comparing int value in java?

Tags: java, object, dictionary, integer, int

I have an issue when i compare `folderInfoData.getFolderInfoRecord().getInfoCode()`  and `map.get("infoCode")`  below code .Both give `value=2` But my issue is that its not enter inside `if` condition.

Here's example :

```
if (folderInfoData.getFolderInfoRecord().getInfoCode().equals(map.get("infoCode"))) {
         showNotification(pageResourceBundle.getText("MSG_SAME_INFO_ALREADY_EXISTS"));
          return;
    }
```

Before i googled its not effective for me:[Comparing Integer objects vs int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036167/comparing-integer-objects-vs-int)

Can anyone tell mehow can resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: what is the return type of `getInfoCode()`

Comment: @Sitansu `Integer` or `int`? As it turns out, that can make a difference.

Comment: What type, *exactly* does `folderInfoData.getFolderInfoRecord().getInfoCode()` return, and how, *exactly* was the `map` declared?

Comment: Map<String, Object> map

Comment: And that would be your problem, right there.

Comment: r u sure, it is not entering into if block. better print the if condition and verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments you state that the `map` was declared `Map<String, Object>`. That's probably the problem.

When you call `map.get("infoCode")` you're getting back an `Object`.

If:

- that `Object` is actually an instance of `Integer`
- `folderInfoData.getFolderInfoRecord().getInfoCode()` is returning an `Integer`
- both `Integer`s contain the same value

Then this:

```
if (folderInfoData.getFolderInfoRecord().getInfoCode()
        .equals(map.get("infoCode"))) {
```

Would evaluate to `true`.

So either they are two `Integers` but don't both contain the same value, or they are different types of objects and are *not* equal. (Or, "infoCode" doesn't exist in the map and it's returning `null`)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `.equals()`, the best way is by make sure it **always** return `Integer` instead of `int`

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(folderInfoData.getFolderInfoRecord().getInfoCode());
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(map.get("infoCode"));

if (new Integer(num1).equals(new Integer(num2))) {
     showNotification(pageResourceBundle.getText("MSG_SAME_INFO_ALREADY_EXISTS"));
      return;
}
```

Comment: Integer num2 = new Integer(map.get("infoCode"));The constructor Integer(Object) is undefined

Comment: @Sitansu if you get _The constructor Integer(Object) is undefined_ thats means `map.get("infoCode")` value is already an `Integer` type

Comment: @DnR No, it means his `Map` is declared `Map<String, Object>` (see the comments). There is no constructor (or `parseInt())` for `Integer` that takes an `Object`

Comment: @BrianRoach yes, and thats why he got the error, because `Integer` constructor only allow either `int` or `string`

Comment: @DnR Right ... but ... read your comment, that's not what you said :-D If it were an `Integer` type already, it would unbox to an `int` and work.

Comment: @BrianRoach Ok, I actually means `Object` not `Integer` -_-

Comment: I suspect one of these things is not like the other.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check *whether both are Integer instances having the correct value so, that is passes equality test*. The test will definitely get pass when both Integer values are same. Please debug your code and find out. There is no use in changing it to `==`.

Comment: Why wouldn't .equals not work and == work? You should explain that, more so since the default implementation of .equals does a reference (==) comparison. Did you intend to say that .equals() overriden implementation in object returned by getInfoCode() is wrong?

Comment: If it's compiling, this is incorrect. A Map can't return a primitive, so aside from causing some un-needed unboxing, it won't make any difference.

Comment: Since these are int values, equality operator should be used. Since they are actual values passed in both sides.Why we shouldn't do it?

Comment: Oh, i am so sorry. I did presume and answered it wrongly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

if it return String

```
if (Integer.parseInt(folderInfoData.getFolderInfoRecord().getInfoCode()) == Integer.parseInt(map.get("infoCode"))) {
         showNotification(pageResourceBundle.getText("MSG_SAME_INFO_ALREADY_EXISTS"));
          return;
    }
```

else

```
if (folderInfoData.getFolderInfoRecord().getInfoCode() == map.get("infoCode")) {
         showNotification(pageResourceBundle.getText("MSG_SAME_INFO_ALREADY_EXISTS"));
          return;
    }
```

try this is also

```
 if (folderInfoData.getFolderInfoRecord().getInfoCode().toString.trim().equals(map.get("infoCode").toString().trim())) {
         showNotification(pageResourceBundle.getText("MSG_SAME_INFO_ALREADY_EXISTS"));
          return;
    }
```

Comment: The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Answer (score -1):

Seems that you are comparing int with an Integer. Java will convert an Integer into an int automatically

So

```
int a = 2;
Integer b = a;
System.out.println(a == b);
```

becomes

```
int a = 2;
Integer b = new Integer(a);
System.out.println(a == b.valueOf());
```

So if you want to use equals, See Rafa El answer. else you can use `==`.