# Java Map Value Equality

Tags: java, hashmap, equality

While writing a graph algorithm, I saw that this -

Definition:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> componentNames = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

CASE I:

```
if (componentNames.get(A) == componentNames.get(B)) {
    System.out.printn("Hi");
}
```

Does not print anything.

CASE II:

```
int componentNameA = componentNames.get(A);
int componentNameB = componentNames.get(B);
if (componentNameA == componentNameB) {
    System.out.printn("Hi");
}
```

Prints "Hi"

I have printed to check the values. And, they were indeed same.
This is the first time I have seen strange behavior for Java.
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What is `A` and `B` in case 1 and case 2??

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/138/autoboxing/538/using-int-and-integer-interchangeably#t=201608270624487872982

Comment: @Hulk +1. OP should use `equals()` instead of `==` to compare objects equality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> CASE I:
>
> ```
> if (componentNames.get(A) == componentNames.get(B)) {
>     System.out.printn("Hi");
> }
> ```

The code doesn't enter the if condition because you are trying to compare two `Integer` references using `==` which will only return true if the LHS and RHS refer to the same object. In your case, it is safe to assume that `componentNames.get(A)` and `componentNames.get(B)` both return a reference to a separate `Integer` object.

It would be helpful to know that the JVM caches the values for wrapper classes and it is quite possible that the above if condition may be true if the JVM has cached the `int` value returned by `componentNames.get(A)` and `componentNames.get(B)`. The JVM used to cache `Integer` values ranging between -128 to 127 but modern JVMs can cache values greater than this range as well.

> ```
> int componentNameA = componentNames.get(A);
> int componentNameB = componentNames.get(B);
> if (componentNameA == componentNameB) {
>     System.out.printn("Hi");
> }
> ```

The code enters condition because you are unboxing an `Integer` into an `int` and the comparison is done between two primitive values.

In general, two references when compared using `==` will only return true if both the references point to the same object. Therefore, it is advisable to compare two references using `equals` if you are checking for equality and compare them using `==` if you are looking to check for identity.

Answer (score -1):

**CASE 1:**

`componentNames.get(A)` and `componentNames.get(B)` are **references / pointers** of two different instances of `Integer` Class.

So, `componentNames.get(A) == componentNames.get(B)` is `false`.

**CASE 2:**

`int componentNameA` and `int componentNameB` are `int` type **variables**.

As they both contain same value, `componentNameA == componentNameB` is `true.`

Comment: Also have a glance at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036167/comparing-integer-objects-vs-int

Comment: This is strictly speaking not correct. `int` is not a reference type, so in case II the variables *hold* the same value rather than referring to the same value, which is why `==` equality is true. @RafafTahsin’ s link should explain the difference better.

Comment: @OleV.V. OMG .. I'm amazed how I did that!!!! fixed.

Comment: That’s fixed alright. I still like the link. :-)

Comment: Thanks man ... @Hulk